Unexpected Invalid Memory Access in Recursive Function for Unique Number Search in CodeWars Challenge
I'm learning c and trying to solve a problem on CodeWars.
Problem Details:

There is an array with some numbers. All numbers are equal except for one. Try to find it!
finduniq((const float[]){1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1}, 5); /* --> 2 */
finduniq((const float[]){0, 0, 0.55, 0, 0}, 5); /* --> 0.55 */

It’s guaranteed that the array contains at least 3 numbers. The tests contain some very huge arrays, so think about performance.

Code
#include <stddef.h>

float wrapper_finduniq(float *nums, size_t n) {
    // Middle one is unique
    if ((*(nums - 1) != *nums) && (*nums != *(nums + 1))) return *nums;
    // Left one is unique
    if ((*(nums - 1) != *nums) && !(*nums != *(nums + 1))) return *(nums - 1);
    // Right one is unique
    if ((!(*nums - 1 != *nums) && (*nums != *(nums + 1)))) return *(nums + 1);
    if (n > 2)
        return wrapper_finduniq(nums + 1, n - 1);
}

float finduniq(const float *nums, size_t n) {
    return wrapper_finduniq((float *)(nums + 1), n - 1);
}

I wrote a wrapper function because the original function operates on a constant pointer, and I need to modify the pointer to traverse the array starting from nums[1] without violating the const qualifier. The wrapper handles the pointer arithmetic and recursive logic while ensuring that the search begins from the second element of the array.
My code works fine and does not access invalid memory portions. The base condition is correct, but I’m getting this weird error.
Error
Test Results:

  Generic_Test
    Completed in 0.5986ms

  Random_Test
    should_return_the_uncheated_unique_number
      Test Crashed
      Caught unexpected signal: SIGSEGV (11). Invalid memory access.
      Completed in 0.0000ms

STDERR
  solution.c:14:1: warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
  }
  ^
  1 warning generated.

Questions

What might be causing the invalid memory access in this recursive function?

Is there a way to improve the robustness of this solution, or should I consider switching to an iterative approach?



what  if the array not contains unique number ?

@NalanPandiKumar That kind of input array will not be provided. I tried this code works fine and it returned correct result in all the tested scenarios.

yeah your test result shows that your code passed in general test

The warning you're getting indicates that there are conditions under which control will reach the end of the function without returning anything.  You're relying on the data to guarantee that won't happen, but the compiler doesn't know that.  Just add something like return 0.0; to the end to keep it happy if you want.  Or better yet, print an error message.

The error is self-explanatory - your code is written as if (n > 2) return wrapper_finduniq(nums + 1, n - 1); else crash_and_burn.

Also note that you're using recursion for a problem that can easily be solved with iteration, so you're needlessly consuming stack space.

@TomKarzes you are correct this error is generated due to stack overflow.

@Peter That kind of input array will not be provided.  Until it is provided.

"the original function operates on a constant pointer" -- no, it doesn't.  The original function has a parameter that is a (modifiable) pointer to const float.  The function could freely modify the value of the parameter (which will be transparent to the caller).  What it cannot do is use the pointer value (directly) to modify the pointed-to float.

Furthermore, even if you could not modify the parameter's value (if it were, say, a float * const), it would be cleaner, clearer, and simpler to create a modifiable local variable for that, or even just a transient value, instead of delegating to a helper function solely for that purpose. (And "helper function" is a much better description than is "wrapper function" for the function you have named wrapper_finduniq).

The remarks about performance in the problem description are somewhat of a red herring.  They may give you the idea that you need to devise a clever algorithm for the job, but a simple linear search can perform this task in only O(N) operations in the worst case, and you cannot do better than that without information about where in the input array the unique value appears.  Without anything to guide you, there is no way to avoid the possibility that you have to examine every array element before you find the unique one.

The error is due to stack overflow. As you mention at the end of your question, you should use an iterative approach.
Some other remarks:

Use index-notation instead of adding to a pointer, it makes the code more readable.

For every value of n you are potentially reading 12 floats. This is far from optimal. Instead you could start by reading one float and for a moment assume it is the common value (not the unique one). Then compare all other values in the array once with that reference value. When you find a difference, there are at most two possibilities: either you found the difference in the very first comparison, and in that case it could be that the chosen reference value was actually the unique outlier (to be verified by comparing with another array value). Or it was not the first comparison and then you are sure you found the outlier.


Here is how that could be written:
float finduniq(const float *nums, size_t n) {
    float ref = nums[0]; // Assume first value is the "common" value, not the outlier
    for (size_t i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (nums[i] != ref) return i > 1 || nums[2] == ref ? nums[i] : ref;
    }
    return ref; // Under the given conditions this would never execute.
}

The ternary expression after the if statement can also be written as a nested if...else statement. And with some additional comments that might be easier to digest:
float finduniq(const float *nums, size_t n) {
    float ref = nums[0]; // Assume first value is the "common" value, not the outlier
    for (size_t i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (nums[i] != ref) {
            if (i > 1) return nums[i]; // There is no doubt here
            // When i==1 we need one more comparison to know the answer
            if (nums[2] == ref) return nums[i];
            return ref; // Our initial assumption turned out to be wrong.
        }
    }
    return ref; // Under the given conditions this would never execute.
}


Yeah you are correct his code indeed uses fifteen memory reads.Your code is nicely optimized.but as beginner I think it's a bit hard to understand these things let him learn and grow.

The ternary expression may come across difficult. I have added a version that uses several if statements with additional comments. The pointer notation that the asker used looks more complex to me than the index notation. I think the latter should actually be easier for a novice to work with. As for comparing with a "reference" value: that seems also easier to me than three times comparing with two neighbors. But I guess what is intuitive for one is complicated for another.

Yeah pointer notation has worst readability than index notation. Myself I was debugged after converting to index notation.

Another alternative along these lines would be to start by using the first three elements to determine the common value (and possibly also the unique value), then afterward run a slightly simpler version of the linear search.  I think that's a bit simpler conceptually, and the code might be a little easier to follow.
